# Adding time and date to a filename

Tags: c, date, time, filenames

I'm trying to write a source file, that would take in the filename/directory and then add current date & time to the end of the file name. So far I've found out that we can use the time() & localtime() functions. However, I'm not quite sure on where to start.

Could someone give me some instructions/steps on the path I could follow to get there?

Thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

- Use `time()` and `localtime()` to get the current time
- Use `strftime()` to format it to the format you want.
- Use `snprintf()` to combine the formatted time with the original file name.
- Use `rename()` to do the actual renaming.

Note that all of the above can be done in one line of `shell` script, so ask yourself whether you really need to do it in C, as opposed to relegating it to `sh`.

Comment: Thanks - updated. He actually mentions that he advanced as far as `localtime()` which is why I didn't mention it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

To get the date/time you have to include `time.h`.
Then you can use the `localtime` function like this:

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
```

The struct `tm` contains the desired information. You can access the day of the month by `tm.tm_mday` and so on.

You can use `sprintf` to write all the date information to a string like this:

```
char datum[128];
sprintf(datum, "%d-%d-%dT%d:%d:%d", tm.tm_year+1900, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);
printf("%s\n", datum);
```

would give something like

```
2013-10-31T20:26:42
```

You can append this string to your filename by using `strcat`

Answer (score 0):

This code will work.

```
char timestr[50];
time_t now = time(NULL);
struct tm *t = localtime(&now);
strftime(timestr, sizeof(timestr)-1, "%m-%d-%Y", t);
timestr[49] = 0;
if((filename = malloc(strlen(argv[2])+strlen(timestr)+1) != NULL) {
filename[0] = '\0';
strcat(filename,argv[2];
strcat(filename,"_");
strcat(filename,timestr);
strcat(filename,".log");
}
```

Just change the argv[2] as per your code argc.